# var flip = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1)) + 0;?

Tags: javascript

I found some code snippets and I'm not sure what it means:

```
var flip = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
```

and

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
```

I'm still getting familiar with Javascript... could someone give me a reader's digest condensed version?

Comment: Read this, it is exactly what you are looking for http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

Comment: See [Generating random numbers in Javascript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1527803/1529630)

Answer (score 0):

`Math.floor()` Round a number downward to its nearest integer

**For example: if you have 2.7 it will round down to 2.**

`Math.random()` Return a random number between 0 and 1

**For example:  .693**